# How can i do pairing on cucumber selenium (automation) project?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to do pairing of cucumber selenium (automation) project.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use BDD for this .

You can check the Step by step development of Framework, jars file that are needed and code.

http://automationcoemadeeasy.blogspot.in/2016/08/cucumber-selenium-integration.html

Hope this will solve your problem.
Thanks,
Rajan